# How to sum value of two values of a json array in java spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

My Api response(for the url http://localhost:8080/findTotSum/12-01-2020/12-02-2020) in JSON format is this

[
{
"id": 121982,
"expdate": null,
"exptype": null,
"expamt": 1000
},
{
"id": 121984,
"expdate": null,
"exptype": null,
"expamt": 54
}
]

I want to sum both the expamt and should get the result as 1054 and should give the response with summed up amount alone if possible

Answer (score 0):

At first you should update API for `/findTotSum` endpoint according to your buisness logic. If you want to get the sum of several values you should choose correct return type.

Second, you need to implement a service for such operations, in this case for sum operation, and use it controller class.

The response can be changed for something like that:

```
Class newResponseWithSum { 
  private List<SomeEntity> list;
  private int sum;
}
```

Comment: thanks , but for now i want to sum the amount value from the json output

Comment: For now your API returns an Array of two objects. If you want to provide additional data in your response you should create a wrapper class, see example above.

Comment: I dont want to provide additional data in my response. sorry for the incorrect statement given in my first statement. I just want to sum the amount values from both array objects and move it to a java string. I think i have the requirement mentioned correct now

Comment: also am not seeing any example u have given "you should create a wrapper class, see example above"

Comment: i am new to java and trying to learn through youtube channels. i am from mainframe background and trying to learn java during my free time. please help

Comment: You should map the response from the API to list of objects, iterate over list and get the sum. 
Or you can try to read int values while parsing json directly